# How to merge dataframes on unique time?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want something like this:

[image]

```
Time    33000CE 33100CE
15:00:00             3.85            5.09 
15:00:03             0.10            1.45 
15:00:06           (0.35)            1.26 
15:00:09           (1.04)            1.10 
15:00:12           (0.76)            1.06 
15:00:16             1.47            3.50 
15:00:19           (0.77)            2.03 
15:00:22           (0.37)            1.91 
15:00:25           (1.64)            1.29 
15:00:28           (0.51)            2.89 
15:00:31             0.91            3.77
```

and I have various dataframes of the form like (ignore other column names for now, but timestamp column is common in all dataframes):

[image]

```
      Time  32600PE
   15:00:01    12.35
   15:00:04    11.30
   15:00:07     9.20
   15:00:10     8.35
   15:00:13     9.95
```

[image]

```
      Time  32500PE
  15:00:01     3.70
   15:00:04     3.50
   15:00:07     3.15
   15:00:10     3.05
   15:00:13     3.65
```

and when i am using concat function:

```
dfList = [df1, df2]
new_df = pd.concat(dfList)
```

i am getting something like this:

[image]

How can i get to my desired result to have rows merged on the time column and not having separate rows for each timestamp?

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: that image does not seem like a merge @rdx

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar So what do I have to do to get to desired result?

Comment: can you share your data and code

Comment: Data is the image given. It;s all that i have. and code is what i have written as pd.concat.

Comment: @rdx can you post the data as text

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar i have added the data as well.

Comment: Hi @rdx, I have written an answer using concat as you asked for, could you please consider accepting the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution using `concat`. We are joining the two dataframe on common index.

##### Creating data

```
# first data frame
d1 = {
    'Time' : ['15:00:01', '15:00:04', '15:00:07', '15:00:10', '15:00:13'],
    '32600PE' : ['12.35', '11.30', '9.20', '8.35', '9.95']
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

# second data frame
d2 = {
    'Time' : ['15:00:01', '15:00:04', '15:00:07', '15:00:10', '15:00:13'],
    '32500PE' : ['3.70', '3.50', '3.15', '3.05', '3.65']
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

##### Concat

```
df = pd.concat([df1.set_index('Time'), df2.set_index('Time')], axis=1)
```

##### Output :

```
         32600PE 32500PE
Time                    
15:00:01   12.35    3.70
15:00:04   11.30    3.50
15:00:07    9.20    3.15
15:00:10    8.35    3.05
15:00:13    9.95    3.65
```

You can reset the `index` and convert `Time` back to column

```
df  = pd.concat([df1.set_index('Time'), df2.set_index('Time')], axis=1).reset_index()
```

##### Output :

```
       Time 32600PE 32500PE
0  15:00:01   12.35    3.70
1  15:00:04   11.30    3.50
2  15:00:07    9.20    3.15
3  15:00:10    8.35    3.05
4  15:00:13    9.95    3.65
```

**EDIT :**

[@Tranbi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72879793/10216112) won't give you all the data in case if there is a time stamp value that is not present in df1 or df2. However concat will take care of that thing and will give `NaN` value for the timestamp value that is not present in other dataframe.

**eg :**  Lets say df1 contains an extra value :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
 'Time': {0: '15:00:01',
          1: '15:00:04',
          2: '15:00:07',
          3: '15:00:10',
          4: '15:00:13',
          5: '15:00:15'},

  '32600PE': {0: 12.35, 1: 11.3, 2: 9.2, 3: 8.35, 4: 9.95, 5: 10.00}}
)
print(df1.merge(df2, on='Time'))
```

Output misses the extra row :

```
       Time  32600PE  32500PE
0  15:00:01    12.35     3.70
1  15:00:04    11.30     3.50
2  15:00:07     9.20     3.15
3  15:00:10     8.35     3.05
4  15:00:13     9.95     3.65
```

[My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72879880/10216112) using concat gives you

```
Time       32600PE  32500PE                
15:00:01    12.35     3.70
15:00:04    11.30     3.50
15:00:07     9.20     3.15
15:00:10     8.35     3.05
15:00:13     9.95     3.65
15:00:15    10.00      NaN
```

`concat` will also take care in case the timestamp values are jumbled in the dataframes

**EDIT2 :**

As [@Tranbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13525512/tranbi) stated, specifying the `kwarg how='outer'` fixes the issue

Comment: Your observation about merge is right, however it is easily fixed with kwarg `how='outer'`. Updating my answer right away...

Answer (score 1):

You can `merge` your dataframes on `Time`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
 'Time': {0: '15:00:01',
          1: '15:00:04',
          2: '15:00:07',
          3: '15:00:10',
          4: '15:00:13'},
  '32600PE': {0: 12.35, 1: 11.3, 2: 9.2, 3: 8.35, 4: 9.95}}
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
 'Time': {0: '15:00:01',
          1: '15:00:04',
          2: '15:00:07',
          3: '15:00:10',
          4: '15:00:13'},
  '32500PE': {0: 3.7, 1: 3.5, 2: 3.15, 3: 3.05, 4: 3.65}}
)

print(df1.merge(df2, on='Time', how='outer'))
```

Output:

```
       Time  32600PE  32500PE
0  15:00:01    12.35     3.70
1  15:00:04    11.30     3.50
2  15:00:07     9.20     3.15
3  15:00:10     8.35     3.05
4  15:00:13     9.95     3.65
```

Edit: specifying `how='outer'` to get all timestamps